# VS MAC: Workload installation failed: One or more errors occured. (The given key 'Microsoft.iOS.Sdk' was not present in the dictionary.)

Tags: ios, macos, .net-6.0, maui

I am trying to build a MAUI app on Mac OS using Visual Studio and I got an error that says to run **dotnet workload install wasm-tools** so I try running it in the Mac terminal in the app project folder and I get the following error.

> Workload installation failed: One or more errors occured. (The given key 'Microsoft.iOS.Sdk' was not present in the dictionary.)

It runs on Visual Studio on Windows for the Android version. I've ensured that everything is updated, including the Mac itself and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Please be noted that it is a `known issue` that is being tracked in [dotnet workload fails with KeyNotFoundException after updating SDKs](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/28217), you can try to run `dotnet workload uninstall ios`, after which you can try to run `dotnet workload restore` which finally should work.

Comment: This updated some things but have the issue I had before which is similar. 

To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: wasm-tools
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload install-wasm-tools (NETSDK1147)

I run the command and it still prompts me this error.

Comment: Have you installed multiple versions of VS code in your machine?

Comment: I have one version of Visual Studio. It's not VS code.

Comment: What is version of your VS? BTW, [In that thread](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/28217), Simon tried to explicitly remove all workloads and then restore them which worked.

Comment: I am running VS 8.10.25 (Build 2) on Mac. I did try to remove all workloads and restore them. I will attempt this again.

Comment: I tried removing all workloads and restoring them and it did not fix the issue. I noticed the error message mentions SDK 6.0.106 but I have 6.0.400 installed. Would it be possible I need to change a target somewhere?

Comment: May I know what the exact error for the SDK 6.0.106?

Comment: Things seem to be resolved in .NET 7. It's been working for now.